# large network latency on localhohst

Tags: networking, dns, voip

I have a laptop, which I want to optimize for voip applications. I experience the problem that applications connecting to localhost suffer from large delays. Basically nothing happens for about 2-3 seconds when one application is connecting to another on the same computer. It looks like an "idle" time.
I asked the question on voip forum, and one of the answers was suggesting that "there is no valid reverse DNS for one of the addresses being used, and aren't even getting definitive "not known" response from the DNS server"

ping localhost returns 0.03ms -not bad

Now , when I do dig e330 (localhost) when the computer is connected to network I get:

```
dig e330

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> e330
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 46557
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e330.              IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           600 IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2015012700 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 27 12:35:08 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 97
```

38msec looks bad.

Then I disconnect the computer from the network and I  do "dig e330" again. This time Query time: 0 msec
However, it doesn't matter whether my laptop is connected to the network or not. The "idle" time is about the same.

From what I read, I see that I can configure DNS and DHCP on my laptop. But I do not want it to run as a server. It is a laptop and it has to connect to other networks everywhere without reconfiguring anything.

What can be done about "reverse DNS" ? (I understand what it is, but I didn't know there is something that can be done about it)
Is there anything else that can be done from Linux point of view to speed up network interfaces in for VOIP applications?

Linux E330 3.13.11-03131111-generic #201411111336 SMP Tue Nov 11 18:55:51 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It seems that it is the same on every Ubuntu machine. At least on 12.04.

This is how I debugged the problem:

- I had Asterisk, Linphone and Wireshark already installed.
  I run all of them.
- I make Wireshark to listen on "lo". Normally there was nothing showing in Wireshark.
- Then I call a `hello world` on *localhost*. I see that the first communication from Linphone to asterisk happens at 0sec, then something happens at 0.5sec, then a long pause and the next packet is almost 3 sec later. That was my problem.

Below is how I fixed it. It gets rid of that long 3 sec delay, although there is still 0.5sec, that I cannot get rid of.

As it turns out *dnsmasq* that comes with *network-manager* was resolving localhost by asking a remote DNS server , opendns in my case.

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` I commented out `#dns=dnsmasq`

then

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo netstat -anlp | grep -w LISTEN
```

kill all running dnsmasq processes

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Then configure dnsmasq, make sure in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` you have

```
# Listen only on localhost
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
```

And this is all. You will have to reboot, I think logout and login should also do.

To see whether your system is currently using Dnsmasq run

```
netstat -ulnp | grep ":53 "
```

You can run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

to see if you are not getting any errors. Now "dig localhost" takes 0sec.

Some links that helped me:
http://sokratisg.net/2012/03/31/ubuntu-precise-dnsmasq/

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing there is actually a failure. It isn't getting an answer locally, then it's searching online and finally giving up with an `NXDOMAIN` error. It's taking so long because it's querying the major root servers which are outside your local network.

Here's what it should look like. This is what I see when I query my hostname:

```
oli@bert:~$ dig bert

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> bert
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25238
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bert.              IN  A

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 27 12:37:37 GMT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 33
```

You'll note that there's no `root-servers.net` activity.

This looks like you probably don't have a line in your `/etc/hosts` that specifies your hostname. Easy enough to fix, just add something like this:

```
127.0.1.1    e330
```

Then try `dig e330` again.

Comment: My /etc/hosts already has this line (it looks a bit different though..)        127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 E330